# weka package not recognized python-weka-wrapper in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, weka

I run on MAC/OS, Python 3.6.3, Anaconda 1.6.9 with Jupiter notebook 5.0.

I was successful installing both javabridge and python-weak-wrapper:

> Successfully installed javabridge-1.0.15 python-weka-wrapper3-0.1.3

However when I go to the notebook and type:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
jvm.start()
```

I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weka'

Any suggestions please?

Comment: python environment? `conda info --envs`

Comment: # conda environments:
#
root                  *  /Users/rod/anaconda3